# Unable to build project that includes Fabric on MacOS10.15

Tags: xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

I included run script on `./Fabric.framework/run` that triggers the below error while build.

> “Fabric.framework” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for
>   malicious software.
>
> This software needs to be updated. Contact the
>   developer for more information.

Also in Security and Privacy settings, there is a message:

> "Fabric.framework" was blocked from opening because it is not from an
>   identified developer.

And the `Open Anyway` button triggers nothing.

So my question is, how to make my project run.?
I am unable to take the build/run, since macOS blocking "Fabric.framework". How to unblock it?

[image]

**OS:** 10.15 Beta (19A501i)

Comment: I am unable to take the build/run, since macOS blocking "Fabric.framework". How to unblock it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @matt. But i can able to run by activating 'Anywhere' opton under `Security & Privacy` settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found one tricky solution.

- Open Terminal and enter command `sudo spctl --master-disable`
- Enter Admin password

it will enable and activate Allow apps downloaded from "**Anywhere**"

You can find this under:

```
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Anywhere
```